# calculate AUC via decision_function for perceptron model

Tags: python, auc, perceptron

I'm try to fit my model using perceptron
and I fit it
but now I need to calculate AUC

it doesn't have predict_proba
but it has decision_function

so, can I calculate AUC using decision_function? It's the same of predict_proba?
or how can I calculate AUC for this model (perceptron)?

Thanks.